# Laravel and Angular. Issue with query results from Laravel when I search using Postman and Chrome

Tags: angular, orm, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I'm using Angular 4 and Laravel 5.4.

When I'm using Postman and querying the next route: http://ventas.dev./api/ubigeo, it return two records because I have the next code:

```
$tot = Ubigeo::where('dist', 'like', '%'. $request->input('term') . '%')->count();
return response()->json(["ubigeo" => $tot], 201);
```

But when I call the same route from Angular it return all records from Ubigeo table.

Why I have this problem?

From Postman:
https://ibb.co/n5PraF

From Chrome (Angular):
https://ibb.co/bW8HFF

Answer (score 0):

How many results do you get when you fire the reuquest directly on your database? Which result are you getting?

Is it possible that there is an error with your custom route? Do you have two server running?

Comment: I have just one server, I have no more.

Comment: Are you sure you are submitting the same `term`-param values in both scenarios? How many entries are there in your database at all? Is 1839 a possible number?

Comment: If you are getting ALL result from your database, this suggests that angular4 might send the request in the wrong encoding. Postman uses `x-www-form-urlencoded` while angular probably uses pure json. Have you tried logging the `term`-value? Probably, while using angular it is empty, which leads to a wrong parameter in the mysql query

Comment: My problem was that I did not send the term variable correctly. I already corrected it, look at my answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

My error was stupid. I was sending a null value in my term variable:

```
let obj = 'term='+term;
```

And it was necessary to do so:

```
let obj = {term: term};
```

All my new Angular function service code is:

```
loadUbigeo(term:string){
    let obj = {term: term};
    let body = JSON.stringify(obj);
    let headers = new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });

    return this.http.post(`${this.sett.url}/ubigeo`, body, { headers })
                    .map(res => {
                      return res.json();
                    });
  }
```